# ¿Cómo puedo almacenar en un array el valor de los input y select que se agregan dinamicamente?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

quisiera saber como puedo almacenar el valor de los option del **select** e **input** en un array ya que cuando doy click al boton "AGREGAR" se añade dinamicamente un input  y un select.

pagina.html

```
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group">
       <button id="add" class="btn btn-primary">Agregar</button>
    </div>
</div> 
    <label for="tipoDepreciacion">Tipo Depreciacion</label>   
    <div id="items">

    </div>
```

archivo.js

```
$("#add").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //Append a new row of code to the "#items" div
    $("#items").append(
        /*'<div><input name="input[]" type="text" /><button class="btn btn-primary delete">-</button></div>'*/
        `<div class="form-row dep_val" style="margin-bottom:3px;">        
            <select id="idDepreciacion">
                <option value="1">Amortización Software</option>
                <option value="2">DA Equipo Computo</option>
                <option value="3">Equipo Computo</option>
                <option value="4">Equipo Diversos</option>
                <option value="5">Infraestructura</option>
                <option value="6">Muebles y Enseres</option>
                <option value="7">Depreciación Asignada</option>
            </select> &nbsp;
            <input class="form-control col-md-2" type="number" required/>  &nbsp;     
            <button class="btn btn-primary delete">-</button>  
        </div>`
    );
});
```

El Select e input se agregan dinamicamente es por ello que deseo almacenar sus valores de ambos en un array.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar [map de jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) para hacer algo así:

```js
$("#add").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  //Append a new row of code to the "#items" div
  $("#items").append(
    /*'<div><input name="input[]" type="text" /><button class="btn btn-primary delete">-</button></div>'*/
    `<div class="form-row dep_val" style="margin-bottom:3px;">        
            <select id="idDepreciacion">
                <option value="1">Amortización Software</option>
                <option value="2">DA Equipo Computo</option>
                <option value="3">Equipo Computo</option>
                <option value="4">Equipo Diversos</option>
                <option value="5">Infraestructura</option>
                <option value="6">Muebles y Enseres</option>
                <option value="7">Depreciación Asignada</option>
            </select> &nbsp;
            <input class="form-control col-md-2" type="number" required/>  &nbsp;     
            <button class="btn btn-primary delete">-</button>  
        </div>`
  );
});

$("#finish").click(function(e) {
  var arr = $.map($('#items .form-row > *:not(button)'), function(n, i) {
    return $(n).val();
  });
  $('#result').html('');
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i+=2) {
    $('#result').append('select: ' + arr[i] + '<br>');
    $('#result').append('input: ' + arr[i + 1] + '<br>');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group">
    <button id="add" class="btn btn-primary">Agregar</button>
    <button id="finish" class="btn btn-primary">Listo</button>
  </div>
</div>
<label for="tipoDepreciacion">Tipo Depreciacion</label>
<div id="items">

</div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Suerte!

Comment: muchas gracias.